# Visual Studio quickstart for *nix / OS X / Xcode developers

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've been writing C/C++ for years using Xcode and am very comfortable with *nix systems. Now I'm working with people who only understand Windows; I've decided to try to learn that environment too.

I was thinking that google would be my best friend, but even the terminology for VS is sufficiently orthogonal to that of Xcode that I can't make any headway. (E.g., what's the equivalent of "Add new Target to project" for VS?)

Can anyone point me to a guide to VS for Xcode practitioners? I've seen lots of translators going the other direction.

Thanks!

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is the Build Configuration Manager in Visual Studio. (It's been a while since I've used XCode). As I recall a "Target" in Xcode is how you want the project built. In VS you get a Debug and Release configuration by default but you can use the Build menu and choose "Configuration..." to create more.

I don't know of a tutorial for XCode users but Kate Gregory has some nice [beginner screencasts on pluralsight](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/Courses/TableOfContents?courseName=vs2010-gettingstarted) for using Visual Studio 2010. Those may get you over some learning curve hurdles. I think they have a 30 day free trial. If you move on to .NET development they have a lot more that can really help you get up to speed quickly.

## Quick Terminology

In Visual Studio you typically create a *Solution*. A solution can consist of any number of *Projects*. You can add projects for .DLLs (libraries), services, applications (gui and console based). You can have multiple applications but can only designate one as the *Startup Project*.

In my typical project I start with the GUI and Add a project of the type I want. Then I often add a library project for new code that I think I can use across multiple applications. Existing code in both supplied libraries and ones you've built are added as **References**. You can right-click on References in the Solution Explorer and select Add References.

In XCode (when I used it) your IDE consisted of two pieces, XCode and Interface Builder. In Visual Studio you can build interface elements directly in Visual Studio ( but there is also a tool called Blend that allows for UI creation and modification). There are THREE major types of interfaces web (usually an ASP.NET application), WinForms and WPF. I think of WinForms as the equivalent of what you build in IB. WPF is the most recent addition and has lots of advantages but a somewhat steep learning curve.

This is probably oversimplified because VS does so much and I'm mostly familiar with the C# and C++/CLI capabilties. However it also supports Visual F#, Iron Python, Iron Ruby, Visual Basic, Sharepoint, Office Integration,Silverlight, XNA,  etc.

Visual Studio is very extensible.  There are lots of extensions to make it integrate with other tools. There are also a couple of extremely useful extensions that make refactoring and writing code easier, my personal favorite is [ReSharper from JetBrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/).

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of any XCode to VS Guide, but according to [XCode Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Targets.html):

> A target specifies a product to build and contains the instructions for building the product from a set of files in a project or workspace.

The analogous concept in Visual Studio would be a **project**.  In Visual Studio, a project contains code files, assets and settings which compile into an output of some sort.  (Could be an executable, a DLL, a website, or a few other options...)  Projects can reference other projects or other external libraries (System or user libraries) which are all delivered together at compile time.

A **solution** contains multiple projects which can be related (referenced) and compiled and linked together.

When you first start VS, it will ask you to Open or Create a project.  It usually will automatically create a solution and automatically add the project to it.  To add additional projects, you can right click the solution in the "Solution Explorer" and add another project.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the feed back. I am slowly learning to map VS jargon onto Xcode jargon. It's so frustrating to feel that my productivity is being throttled by drop-down menus that don't make any sense.

Comment: I should have mentioned in my response that the context-sensitive right mouse click is VERY useful. Open the Solution Explorer window and right-click on the Solution, then try it on a Project.  Pay particular attention to the *Properties...* choices at the bottom and the "Add" item in the middle which opens a sub-menu. A useful gem in the Project context menu is near the bottom *Open Folder in Windows Explorer*.